# Calling LDAP server in GAE Flex Node throws 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup' error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ldap

I am using ldapjs package for ldap authentication in my nodejs application which is deployed on google cloud app engine flexible environment.

The code is working fine when I run in my local machine. But it is failing on GCP.

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');

var client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://ldap.abc.com'
});

var opts = {
    filter: '(alias='+username+')',
    scope: 'sub'
};
```

This code is working when I run in my local machine. This application is deployed on GCP App Engine using flex environment. I am getting the below error when I run this code from google cloud environment.

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ldap.abc.com ldap.abc.com:389 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
```

Comment: Is ldap.abc.com:389 publically accessible?

Comment: are you using any [network settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#network_settings) in the app.yaml?

Comment: are you connected to a VPN in your local pc?

Comment: are you still facing this issue?